# Symfony 4 - LiipImagine - How to clear cache?

Tags: symfony

on symfony 4 I use LiipImagineBundle for the display of my images.
But I noticed that there were cache problems.
My config is:

```
# See dos how to configure the bundle: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/basic-usage.html
liip_imagine:
  # valid drivers options include "gd" or "gmagick" or "imagick"
  driver: "gd"
  filter_sets:
    cache: ~

    # the name of the "filter set"
    avatar_big:
      # adjust the image quality to 75%
      quality: 75

      # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
      filters:
        # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
        # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
        thumbnail: { size: [120, 120], mode: outbound }
```

My images are in :

```
public\images\avatar\
```

Is there a way to automatically clear the cache? I saw that there were orders to be made but I wonder if we can automate all that

Answer (score 9):

If you mean to delete the cache images generated by your imagine filters, then LiipImagineBundle adds a command to Symfony console that does that:

```
php bin/console liip:imagine:cache:remove
```

Without any parameters, you will delete cache images for all paths and all filters.

You can use parameters to narrow the deletion to whatever filters and paths you want, like this:

```
php bin/console liip:imagine:cache:remove path1 path2 --filters=thumb1 --filters=thumb2
```

You have more information and examples here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/commands.html#remove-cache

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a solution if I want to automatically delete the cache image in case the image is deleted or updated?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with an Event Listener. There is a Symfony-based e-commerce framework called Sylius that uses LiipImagineBundle and they do it like this:
[ImagesRemoveListener.php](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/EventListener/ImagesRemoveListener.php)

They also use KnpGaufretteBundle so you may have to adapt it to your implementation (i.e., you may not have the ImageUploaderInterface and you should get a way to find your items in the filesystem)

Comment: Okay ! I see the operation, but suddenly for it to work, it must be able to access the path of the image, thanks to a $ image-> getPath (), finally it takes an attribute in my entity that represents the path where reside l 'picture. This is the path of the base image or the one created by LiipImagineBundle? How can I implement this?

Comment: It all depends on your implementation. I mean who generates the path when a file is uploaded. For example, if you use VichUploaderBundle, you can use its [Helper](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/generating_urls.md) to get the correct path to your images. If you use KnpGaufretteBundle, you can use the adapter and/or filesystem you configured to get the correct path to your images.

Comment: I use VichUploaderBundle ! So, if I create a listener, I can get the image path with VichUploader ?

Comment: I think so. Not sure how, I don't use VichUploader myself right now. Just ignore the Helper link I put in my last comment because that's to generate URLs, not paths

Comment: Actually, VichUploaderBundle has its own EventListeners: https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/events.md.
Just create your EventListener with the event `vich_uploader.post_remove` and send the CacheManager and FilterManager from LiipImagineBundle as arguments into that EventListener of yours. Then use the `delete_on_remove` and/or `delete_on_update` in your VichUploader configuration file. And that should be it, you'll be able to tell the cache manager to delete all related images any time an image managed by VichUploaderBundle is deleted.

Comment: I will make a new post. I tried to make a listener but I've a problem :s